# Manipulating ideal generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Given the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\vartheta)$ with $\vartheta = \sqrt{-73}$, I'm trying to determine the structure of the class group $\mathrm{Cl}(K)$. By using the Minkowski Theorem and Kummer-Dedekind Theorem, I determined that $\mathrm{Cl}(K)$ is generated by the ideal classes of the ideals
$$
\mathfrak{p}_{2} = \langle 2, \vartheta - 1 \rangle, \hspace{20pt} \mathfrak{p}_{71} = \langle 7, \vartheta - 2 \rangle, \hspace{20pt} \mathfrak{p}_{72} = \langle 7, \vartheta + 2 \rangle,
$$
where
$$
\mathfrak{p}_{2}^{2} = \langle 2 \rangle, \hspace{20pt} \mathfrak{p}_{71}\mathfrak{p}_{72} = \langle 7 \rangle.
$$
Thus, by writing $[\mathfrak{p}_{i}]$ for the ideal class of the ideal $\mathfrak{p}_{i}$, we have
$$
[\mathfrak{p}_{2}]^{2} = [1] \hspace{20pt}\text{and}\hspace{20pt} [\mathfrak{p}_{71}][\mathfrak{p}_{2}] = [1]
$$
so that
$$
[\mathfrak{p}_{2}] = [\mathfrak{p}_{2}]^{-1} \hspace{20pt}\text{and}\hspace{20pt} [\mathfrak{p}_{71}] = [\mathfrak{p}_{2}]^{-1}.
$$
I'm trying to determine the order of and relationship between the ideal classes. For example, I tried to determine the product $[\mathfrak{p}_{2}][\mathfrak{p}_{71}]$ by finding the product $\mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}$. This is where I encounter an issue.

By expressing the ideals as their generators, we have
$$
\mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71} = \langle 2, \vartheta - 1 \rangle\langle 7, \vartheta - 2 \rangle = \langle 14, 2\vartheta - 4, 7\vartheta - 7, -71 + 3\vartheta \rangle
$$
since $\vartheta^{2} = -73$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{c}
  (-71 + 3\vartheta) + 5(14) = -1 + 3\vartheta \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71},\\
  (-7 + 7\vartheta) - 3(2\vartheta - 4) = 5 + \vartheta \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71},\\
  (-4 + 2\vartheta) - 5(-1 + 3\vartheta) = 1 - 13\vartheta \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71},\\
  13(5 + \vartheta) + (1 - 13\vartheta) = 66 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}.\\
\end{array}
$$
Now $66 - 4(14) = 10 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}$, and then $14 - 10 = 4 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}$, so that $14 - 2(4) = 2 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}$.

Now that $2 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71}$, we can observe that
$$
(5 + \vartheta) - 3(2) = \vartheta - 1 \in \mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71},
$$
and then each of the generators
$$
14, 2\vartheta - 4, 7\vartheta - 7, -71 + 3\vartheta
$$
are $\mathbb{Z}[\vartheta]$-linear combinations of $2$ and $\vartheta - 1$, so
$$
\mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71} = \langle 2, \vartheta - 1 \rangle\langle 7, \vartheta - 2 \rangle = \langle 14, 2\vartheta - 4, 7\vartheta - 7, -71 + 3\vartheta \rangle = \langle 2, \vartheta - 1 \rangle = \mathfrak{p}_{2}
$$
and thus
$$
\mathfrak{p}_{2}\mathfrak{p}_{71} = \mathfrak{p}_{2}.
$$
This does not feel right at all. Have I just made a silly mistake somewhere, or is there something going on that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use [sage](http://www.mathsage.org)
to make the computations. First of all, let us have a clear picture of the class group of the given field. Code:

```
K.<t> = QuadraticField( -73 )
G = K.class_group()
print "K = %s" % K
print "G = Cl(K) is %s" % G
print "G has %s generator(s)" % len(G.gens())
```

Results:

```
K = Number Field in t with defining polynomial x^2 + 73
G = Cl(K) is Class group of order 4 with structure C4 of Number Field in t with defining polynomial x^2 + 73
G has 1 generator(s)
```

Sage uses the generator:

```
sage: G.gens()
(Fractional ideal class (7, t + 5),)
```

Now back to the post.

```
sage: p2  = K.ideal( 2, t-1 )
....: p71 = K.ideal( 7, t-2 )
....: p72 = K.ideal( 7, t+2 )
....: 
sage: p2*p2
Fractional ideal (2)
sage: p71*p72
Fractional ideal (7)
sage: p71*p2
Fractional ideal (14, t + 5)
sage: p72*p2
Fractional ideal (14, t + 9)
```

So the class of $\mathfrak p_2\cdot \mathfrak p_{72}$ is not trivial.

The error was in the first line of the computation, note that

```
sage: (t-1)*(t-2)
-3*t - 71
```

so there is a minus three as coefficient. The difference is:

```
sage: q = K.ideal( 14, 2*t-4, 7*t-7, -71+3*t )    # false +3 coeff
sage: q
Fractional ideal (2, t + 1)
sage: q == p2*p71
False
sage: q == p2
True
sage: K.ideal( 14, 2*t-4, 7*t-7, -71-3*t )    # coeff -3 is ok
Fractional ideal (14, t + 5)
sage: p2*p71 == _
True
```

(The underscore stays for the "last result so far".)

Comment: Such a simple mistake! This is fantastic though, thank you. I've used sage for elliptic curves, but I didn't realise that it had the capability to deal with ideals.

Comment: I highly appreciate the quality of the computations, despite of the one error. It is known, i can sign up, that the same eyes will never find such an error. It happens to me again and again. But finding systematic errors is easy, better, when this happens quickly, and best when one shares the own computations. This site is doing a good job for this. I must mention, i learned again a lot from this example!